# Is there a c/c++ function out there to detect circles in the edge map of an image

Tags: c++, opencv

I have already tried OpenCV's HoughCircles (which takes grayscale images as input), which is not giving very favorable results. I want to findthe circles in the edge image because I could clean up the unnecessary edges thus reducing the scope for any confusion.

So is there a function that will find circles from the canny edges of the image?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of images are you dealing with? What background do they have? If possible attach some pictures of your images.

Comment: If it isn't in OpenCV, it probably isn't anywhere... maybe in some academic articles someone wrote up a technique for it? That happens a lot. Those can be hard to wade through for a non-academic type though.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. @Proxy : I might have to get permission before I can upload any images. Will try to upload one soon.

Comment: @Vishy : since OpenCV is open source and HoughCircles uses gradient extraction internally, it might be easy to copy/paste most of the HoughCircles method and add a canny-edge/gradient image as a parameter instead of computing it within that method.